# node inspector error error on Node LTS 8.9.0

Tags: node.js, npm, node-inspector

When I'm running `npm i` with Node v6, the installation passes with no errors, and when i'm looking for node-inspector, I receive:

```
  ~/Development/<project-name>(master*) » npm ls node-inspector                                                                                                                                                                                                       chenn@chenn-mac
    JPMS@2.0.0 /Users/chenn/Development/<project-name>
    └── (empty)
```

So node-inspector is not a part of the dep tree.

However, when I switch the Node LTS 8.9.0 and running the installation command (after removing /node_modules directory) I receive the following:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/profiler/v5.7.0/node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-profiler@5.7.0 and node@8.9.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think Node.js changed the debug tools, from 6.3 onward you can use --inspect instead of --debug and debugger is directly accessible on chrome with about:inspect.

On this blog you can find more information.
https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27